Do we need to memorize every command of Linux OS Terminal Shell?
This is a rare question that I can ask from the experts that every time I use a command for the Linux OS Terminal Shell. Do I need to memorize every command in the Command Line Interface (CLI) of Linux Mint 20.3 "Ulayana"? As I am doing the Google Cybersecurity Certification Course on Coursera. I see a lot of Linux Labs in this course as it makes me challenging to learn these commands. Is there any Linux Cheat Sheet of Commands of the terminal of the Command Line Interface (CLI)?

So, are you learning Linux to use Linux or you are trying to pass a certain certification exam? These are two different questions that may have very different answers. I've been using it for over 25 years and I certainly don't know all the shell commands, there's just too many and some are absolutely obscure and required for very special tasks I've never accomplished. And I don't know the vast majority of command options because again, I've not needed them. Learning everything sounds kinda insane.

If it takes me more than three minutes to find how to do something (using man -k, Google, and forums), I add a comment with my own search keywords, and an example of the command, to a README.txt.  350 lines so far.

Use Harry Potter as an example, they know lots of spells and the more you know the more powerful wizard you are.
You can cheat of course, nobody knows all commands but you need to have an idea, what commands are there so you can google at least.
Also install fish shell next to bash and use it, it helps you in many ways and is user friendly.

I suggest you learn and memorize gradually by simply using the terminal as much as you can. It takes time. I also recommend getting familiar with the apropos and man commands. To me personally, it's always been about understanding how the OS works above everything else.

Make your own cheat sheet. The process of doing it yourself will enhance the memorization effectiveness. Plus it will only list the commands YOU encounter/use/need.
